# Store value from a PostgreSQL record and update by Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to update a field of certain records in the REC table instead of doing a new insert.
What I do is to use a TEMP table where I insert records. Then I check if the records are present in the REC table. If yes, I want to update a particular field ("num") by adding the current value (in the TEMP table) to the old one (in REC). To do this I use the fetchall() function to store the values of the "num" column (from the records in TEMP and from REC).

I run the following code to collect the value of "num" from REC and TEMP and to do the update.

```
for i j in zip(res1, res2):
  i = list (i)
  j = list(j)
  j[12]+= i[12]
  cursor.execute ("UPDATE REC SET num = %s ;" % (j[12]))
```

In res1 I store the matched records of the TEMP and in res2 the matched records of the REC.

However this results in nonsense values in the field "num" and is updated for the whole records (even those which didn't match)

Comment: Any idea to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `WHERE` ?

`cursor.execute ("UPDATE REC SET num = %s WHERE num = %s;" % (j[12], j[12]))`

It would also help if I could see more of your code. I believe there might be an easier way to do what you are trying to do.